# NASM and Syntastic: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode

Tags: plugin-syntastic, filetype-assembly

Whenever using NASM, and syntactic I get the warning

> instruction not supported in 16-bit mode

How do I provide the argument to tell it to not use 16-bit mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default in NASM, try using the [`BITS`](https://github.com/rpavlik/assembler/blob/master/doc/manual/nasm-directives.txt) directive by putting

```
BITS 64;
```

at the top of the `.asm` file.